# Pandas read_csv is converting integers of csv file into floats in data-frame. dtype or converter options aren't working either

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading a csv file uisng read_csv function and creating a dataframe. The dataframe is adding ".0" to integers in the csv file meaning converting the integers into floats. Concerned column represents number of service anniversary of employees and I don't want them in floats. Any work around to this problem.

***csv file data row =>
`Staten Island,NY,10307,,,,,1/4/2019,3`

**dataframe =>
 `Staten Island   NY  10307                   1/4/2019    3.0`

I tried using `dtype=str` option of read_csv and also tried passing `converters` dictionary to convert every column into string. That did not work either.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: the column might have `nan` values so that the whole columns is converted to `float`.

Comment: Yes. only the header row does not have any value for this column. If I put a header like "years of service" into the header row then this column is not being converted to float. However this is the client data and I can not edit it before parsing since the other client may not have header row at all. Meaning I can not edit header row.

Comment: I don't understand why Pandas is manipulating the data for no reason.